# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting

Tags: shell, command-line-interface

I am trying to run this command:
curl -L https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/releases/download/$version/migrate.$platform-amd64.tar.gz | tar xvz

and the error looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Amm5.png)

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: This is an invalid URL, you are supposed to substiture the $... parts for the version number and OS. For example: https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/releases/download/v4.15.1/migrate.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding a 404 error page into tar (after gzip), and gzip says *I can't read html pages*